# nginx reverse proxy is not working for asp.net core docker app

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, asp.net-core-3.1

I have asp.net web api application in docker container and it's working good with below commands,

```
 docker build -t hello-aspnetcore3 -f Api.Dockerfile .
 docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name hello-aspnetcore3  hello-aspnetcore3
```

Browse to: http://localhost:5000/weatherforecast works perfect.

Now I am trying to use `Nginx` as reverse proxy and running in another container and here is nginx conf  and container files,

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

sendfile on;

upstream web-api {
    server api:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $hostname;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://web-api;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
  }
}
```

**Nginx.Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:latest

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

and here is my docker compose file,

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.7"

services:

reverseproxy:
build:
  context: ./Nginx
  dockerfile: Nginx.Dockerfile
ports:
  - "80:80"
restart: always

api:
depends_on:
  - reverseproxy
build:
  context: ./HelloAspNetCore3.Api
  dockerfile: Api.Dockerfile
expose:
  - "5000"
restart: always
```

Building and running containers are fine `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up -d`.

But when trying to browse `http://localhost/weatherforecast`, it's giving `HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.` error. What's wrong here?

**Note - when I browse using host ip address `http://192.168.0.103/weatherforcast`, then it's works fine.**

`Docker-Compose ps` output is here....

[image]

Comment: How is port mapping?  `Docker-Compose ps`

Comment: @abestrad, thanks for your response. Please see the output for `Docker-Compose ps` in last section of my question (edited)

Comment: Your Nginx config looks good. Try to change your upstream port `api:80` instead of `api:5000`.

Comment: no luck even after changing to `80`. Thanks for reply.